# What are the benefits of using MP-BGP multicast address family, under the context of inter PIM domains multicasting?

Tags: cisco, bgp, multicast, pim

Under the context of inter PIM domains multicasting, 1 RP on each PIM domain (2 domains), attached with eBGP, with MSDP peering to exchange the actives sources, what are the benefits of using the MB-BGP multicast address family ?

Cisco mention in some documentation the usage of MP-BGP Multicast in this context (e.g: https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/global/fr_ca/training-events/pdfs/Interdomain_IPMulticast.pdf, slide 21)

Comment: Compared to what?

Comment: Compared to MSDP only

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Bandwidth conservation as you can go into sparse mode and only downstream or east-west content that is in use, rather than broadcast all content at all times. Upstream traffic is also unicast and therefore not propagated unnecessarily.

Here is a Juniper Networks resource that goes over this thoroughly. The network theory is the same. just different vendor specific command structure.

https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/concept/ng-mvpn-topology.html